# How to fit data to a convolution equation

Tags: fitting, signal-processing, convolution

How to fit data to a convolution equation:

```
m1data = Import["http://pastebin.com/raw/GckJAgpY", "Table"];
m2data = Import["http://pastebin.com/raw/5HvwSg7i", "Table"];
ListLinePlot[{m1data,m2data},PlotRange-> All]
```

[image]

Objective function:

```
m2[t] == m1[t] + a1*Integrate[m1[tau]*Exp[-a2 (t - tau)], {tau, 0, t}]
```

Is it possible to estimate a1 and a2 from the data?

Comment: You mean without proposing a model for `m1data`?

Comment: @Dr.belisarius  not sure, we have input and output data, can it be possible. I will  try to add the model for m1data.

Comment: Do you mean `m1[tau]` or `m1[t]` ?  If the former, do you not need to give the definition of `m1[tau]` in the solution of the ODE ?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 0) Browse the [common pitfalls](http://goo.gl/zpsUsd) question 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 2) Read the [faq]! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I wasn't sure how to set it up with the standard fit functions, so I just rolled my own least squares.  (It probably can be done, but I had an inkling I might want to have greater control over the computation.  I hope it helps.)

I start by defining `m1` and `m2` on your data:

```
Clear[m1, m2];
(m1[t_] /; t == First@# = Last@#) & /@ m1data;
(m2[t_] /; t == First@# = Last@#) & /@ m2data;
```

Then I defined the convolution, using the trapezoid rule and based on a consisted delta `t` of `0.1` in both data sets.

```
ClearAll[ni];
SetAttributes[ni, Listable];
ni[0. | 0, _] := 0.;
mem : ni[t_?NumericQ, a2_?NumericQ] := mem = Quiet[
   NIntegrate[m1[tau]*Exp[-a2 (t - tau)], {tau, 0, t}, 
    Method -> {"TrapezoidalRule", "Points" -> 1 + Round[t/0.1]}, 
    MaxRecursion -> 0],
   NIntegrate::ncvb]
```

The objective function is the sum of squares of the residuals the solution to your ODE.  This is to be minimized.

```
obj = m2[t] - (m1[t] + a1*ni[t, a2]) /. {m1[t] -> m1data[[All, 2]], 
     m2[t] -> m2data[[All, 2]], t -> m1data[[All, 1]]} // #.# &;
```

The value for `a1` is consistent, but the model is not very sensitive to `a2`.  It's always a big value, which suggests only `t = tau` is contributing much to the convolution.

```
FindMinimum[obj, {{a1, -1.}, {a2, 100}}]
(*  {1.20002, {a1 -> -20.173, a2 -> 266.816}}  *)

FindMinimum[obj, {{a1, -13.}, {a2, 1550}}]
(*  {1.20002, {a1 -> -20.173, a2 -> 1550.}}  *)

FindMinimum[obj, {{a1, -20.}, {a2, 50}}]
(*  {1.20002, {a1 -> -20.173, a2 -> 2250.22}}  *)

FindMinimum[obj2, {{a1, -53.}, {a2, 4500}}]
(*  {1.20002, {a1 -> -20.173, a2 -> 4500.}}  *)
```

Note: The trapezoid rule in `NIntegrate` uses Romberg quadrature.  If you turn it off, then `a1` is consistently `-13.4487` and `a2` is very large just as before.